# How can I swap two color in one image in windows form application?

Tags: c#

I need to swap two color in one image like in the link:
Like this :

[image]

this code not correct 
but I need code to do like this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(tsttPic.Image);

    int width = bmp.Width;

    int height = bmp.Height;


    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {

            Color p = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

            int a = p.A;
            int r = p.R;
            int g = p.G;
            int b = p.B;
            if (r == 255 && b == 255 && b == 255)
            {
                r = 0;
                g = 128;
                b = 255;

            }
            else
            {
                r = 255;
                g = 255;
                b = 255;
            }
            bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b));
        }

    }

    neggPic.Image = bmp;
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to provide more information? In [ask] you find more information to improve your question.

Comment: Thank you for providing your code. Please can you also include what happens when you run this code, and why it isn't what you want. Also, please upload your screenshot here.

Comment: Done
is it good?

Comment: this code isn't working for any image
just because I know the color of the image I wrote my code in this way
if you changed the photo this code is wrong

Comment: You might also need to tell us if `tsttPic.Image` is a loaded from a bitmap (or other lossless file format), or from a lossy format (e.g. jpeg) since in lossy formats, colours won't be exact.

Comment: Oh, so you need a universal solution? That could be tricky (see on my previous comment). For best results, you'll probably either want a) the user to select both colours, and a threshold, or b) find the most common colours in the image and allow the user to choose a threshold.

Comment: Yes that's what I want

Comment: the photo is loaded from properties (Image) of PictureBox

Comment: OK, but the `PictureBox` control doesn't just magically have an image in it. It's loaded from a file, either at design time or runtime, or manually drawn using GDI in code, right?

Comment: Of course! so no way just if the user insert the colors?

Comment: Essentially you need to look at all of the pixels in the image, and try and separate them into two buckets. For bitmaps, and other lossless formats, this will be quite simple (assuming the image only has 2 colours), but for lossy formats you'll need to have some kind of threshold for determining if two colours are "the same".

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try.

Comment: There are ways to replace or swap colors. But they all hinge on the colors being actually the same. So if your image has only two colors you could use [colormapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormap?view=netframework-4.8) but if there are variations (as in every anitliased image and also in every jpg source) this will not work.. (Well a few variations may actually be included in the color maps ;-)

Comment: How did you do it then?

Comment: @TaW its just for two colors :::  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z-UwJpjuzuT9W-WiZifQWAeS_OicK5ptL6aEE7M_Bv4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, this will be very slow., though.To speed it up you can use LockBits or go for ColorMaps..

Comment: Thank you ,I'll try